# Date not rendering in Django template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I am attempting to pass date values from `views.py` (passed in from `managers.py`), but they are not rendering in my template.

I made sure that the date value is correct by printing it to the console and adding it to my template. It renders fine without any filters, but when I used the exact same syntax from earlier in my project—where it worked—all I get are blank values.

#### managers.py

```py
tz = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')

class ProfileManager(Manager):
    def index(self, request):
        profile = models.Profile.objects.get(user__pk=request.session['id']) \
            if 'id' in request.session else None

        appts = []
        next_appt = None

        if profile != None:
            try:
                next_appt = Appointment.objects.get(
                    profile=profile,
                    date_end__gt=datetime.now(pytz.utc),
                )
            except Appointment.DoesNotExist:
                next_appt = None
            except MultipleObjectsReturned:
                next_appt = Appointment.objects.filter(
                    profile=profile,
                    date_end__gt=datetime.now(pytz.utc),
                ).first()

            appts = Appointment.objects \
                .filter(date_end__gt=datetime.now(pytz.utc)) \
                .exclude(profile__user=None)

        return {
            'profile': profile,
            'next_appt': next_appt,
            'appts': appts,
            'TIME_ZONE': TIME_ZONE,
            'current_date': datetime.now(tz),
        }
```

#### views.py

```py
def index(request):
    response = Profile.objects.index(request)

    return render(request, 'users/index.html', response)
```

#### index.html

```html
<div id="datePickerDate">
  {{ current_date }}
  <input type="hidden" name="year" value="{{ current_date|date:'Y' }}" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="hidden" name="month" value="{{ current_date|date:'n' }}" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

#### Result

```html
<div id="datePickerDate">
  Aug. 19, 2019, 4:27 p.m.
  <input name="year" value="" autocomplete="off" type="hidden">
  <input name="month" value="" autocomplete="off" type="hidden">
</div>
```

I can't think of what I'm missing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense at all. What is that index method supposed to be doing? Why is it defined in a Manager? Why does it take a request parameter? Where is the rest of the method?

Comment: I've added the rest of index in `managers.py`, although none of it is related to dates. It takes information from the user's profile and populates the return value with data necessary for the template.

Comment: It's defined in a Manager to keep `views.py` from getting cluttered by logic that doesn't explicitly deal with requests. As you'll see from the edit, the request object is passed to take in a value from Session.

Comment: Perhaps the `date` variable in your context is shadowing the built-in `date` filter - try `current_date` in the dict you return from `index` and `"{{ current_date|date:'Y'}}"` in your template and see if that helps.

Comment: Changing the variable name yields the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue was in my JavaScript. I was adding values to the input fields though jQuery without realizing it, and those values were `undefined`. It appears I should be more cognizant of what code I actually need when I copy and paste code from other parts of a project, or any other source for that matter.